# How to show CR in Geany

Tags: text-editors, newlines, geany, control-characters

Can Geany be switched into a mode where it displays `CR` characters (but not `LF` characters)?

Can Geany be forced to only wrap a line on `LF` but not on `CR`?

**Generally speaking:**

Geany wraps a line on all three possible forms of a line ending: a single `CR`, a single `LF` or a `CR LF` sequence. I would expect that a line wrap is only done on the proper line ending set in the preferences of the document; all other variants shall be handled as stray control characters.

I can live with the line wrapping on all three, but in that case I still want to know when the correct line ending is not present in the file.

There is an option to display all line endings, but this is plainly unusable, as having the proper line ending displayed everywhere is so frustrating that I wouldn't want to use Geany at all.

**Why Geany:**

With a `tty` I am used to `vi` and `emacs`.  But under Windows I was used to `Ultraedit`.

Now that Ultraedit became unacceptable for me (a longer story to tell) I looked for a replacement and found Geany, which offers everything I expect from a text editor, like `indent 2`, `tab 8` and `block edit mode`.

The only thing I really miss is a proper display of stray control characters like `CR`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Geany is not able to do this and most likely will not unless somebody is adding a plugin for, hacking Scintilla default behavior.

Comment: Is it difficult to hack Scintilla to show line endings? Notepad++ is Scintilla and can.